# In R, how can specific columns be transposed to rows, aligning with the original values?

Tags: r, dataframe, pivot, transpose

When I organize data sheet, I made this way.

```
A <- data.frame(
  Season = rep(2023, 5),
  crop = rep("Soybean", 5),
  treatment = rep("Inside panel", 5),
  plot = rep(6, 5),
  row = 1:5,
  rep1 = c(24.30, 30.30, 21.80, 22.90, 20.60),
  rep2 = c(10.30, 0.00, 29.30, 0.00, 30.80),
  rep3 = c(30.70, 28.40, 15.50, 22.30, 17.40),
  SS1 = c("tr1", "tr1", "tr1", "tr3", "tr1"),
  SS2 = c("tr3", "tr2", "tr2", "tr2", "tr3"),
  SS3 = c("tr2", "tr3", "tr3", "tr1", "tr2")
)

  Season    crop    treatment plot row rep1 rep2 rep3 SS1 SS2 SS3
1   2023 Soybean Inside panel    6   1 24.3 10.3 30.7 tr1 tr3 tr2
2   2023 Soybean Inside panel    6   2 30.3  0.0 28.4 tr1 tr2 tr3
3   2023 Soybean Inside panel    6   3 21.8 29.3 15.5 tr1 tr2 tr3
4   2023 Soybean Inside panel    6   4 22.9  0.0 22.3 tr3 tr2 tr1
5   2023 Soybean Inside panel    6   5 20.6 30.8 17.4 tr1 tr3 tr2
```

SS1 align with rep1, and SS2 align with rep2, and SS3 align with rep3. For example, in the first row, 24.3 is for tr1, and 10.3 is for tr3, and 30.7 is for tr2.

What I want is to transpose SS columns into rows.

```
B=data.frame(
  Season = rep(2023, 15),
  crop = rep("Soybean", 15),
  treatment = rep("Inside panel", 15),
  plot = rep(6, 15),
  row = rep(1:5, each = 3),
  rep = rep(1:3, times = 5),
  SS = c("tr1", "tr3", "tr2", "tr1", "tr2", "tr3", "tr1", "tr2", "tr3", "tr3", "tr2", "tr1", "tr1", "tr3", "tr2"),
  yield = c(24.30, 10.30, 30.70, 30.30, 0.00, 28.40, 21.80, 29.30, 15.50, 22.90, 0.00, 22.30, 20.60, 30.80, 17.40))

   Season    crop    treatment plot row rep  SS yield
1    2023 Soybean Inside panel    6   1   1 tr1  24.3
2    2023 Soybean Inside panel    6   1   2 tr3  10.3
3    2023 Soybean Inside panel    6   1   3 tr2  30.7
4    2023 Soybean Inside panel    6   2   1 tr1  30.3
5    2023 Soybean Inside panel    6   2   2 tr2   0.0
6    2023 Soybean Inside panel    6   2   3 tr3  28.4
7    2023 Soybean Inside panel    6   3   1 tr1  21.8
8    2023 Soybean Inside panel    6   3   2 tr2  29.3
9    2023 Soybean Inside panel    6   3   3 tr3  15.5
10   2023 Soybean Inside panel    6   4   1 tr3  22.9
11   2023 Soybean Inside panel    6   4   2 tr2   0.0
12   2023 Soybean Inside panel    6   4   3 tr1  22.3
13   2023 Soybean Inside panel    6   5   1 tr1  20.6
14   2023 Soybean Inside panel    6   5   2 tr3  30.8
15   2023 Soybean Inside panel    6   5   3 tr2  17.4
```

Could you let me know how to convert transpose columns to rows, aligning with the original values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:** see input of @Onyambu:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

A %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = c(starts_with("rep"), starts_with("SS")),
    names_to = c(".value", NA),
    names_pattern = "(rep|SS)(\\d+)"
  )
```

**First answer:**
We could do it this way: It is the compact mode of using pivot_longer twice:

We use `names_to = c(".value", "set")` and `names_pattern = "(rep|SS)(\\d+)"` to separate the column names into two parts. `.value` keeps the common part of the column names (rep and SS), and `set` keeps the numeric suffix (and is removed afterwords).

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

A %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = c(starts_with("rep"), starts_with("SS")),
    names_to = c(".value", "set"),
    names_pattern = "(rep|SS)(\\d+)"
  ) %>%
  select(-set)
```

```
  Season crop    treatment     plot   row   rep SS   
    <dbl> <chr>   <chr>        <dbl> <int> <dbl> <chr>
 1   2023 Soybean Inside panel     6     1  24.3 tr1  
 2   2023 Soybean Inside panel     6     1  10.3 tr3  
 3   2023 Soybean Inside panel     6     1  30.7 tr2  
 4   2023 Soybean Inside panel     6     2  30.3 tr1  
 5   2023 Soybean Inside panel     6     2   0   tr2  
 6   2023 Soybean Inside panel     6     2  28.4 tr3  
 7   2023 Soybean Inside panel     6     3  21.8 tr1  
 8   2023 Soybean Inside panel     6     3  29.3 tr2  
 9   2023 Soybean Inside panel     6     3  15.5 tr3  
10   2023 Soybean Inside panel     6     4  22.9 tr3  
11   2023 Soybean Inside panel     6     4   0   tr2  
12   2023 Soybean Inside panel     6     4  22.3 tr1  
13   2023 Soybean Inside panel     6     5  20.6 tr1  
14   2023 Soybean Inside panel     6     5  30.8 tr3  
15   2023 Soybean Inside panel     6     5  17.4 tr2
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! You saved my time a lot!! Many thanks!!!

Comment: instead of `select(-set)` use `names_to = c('.value', NA)` or use `names_to = '.value'` with a pattern capturing only the first part ie, `names_pattern = "(rep|SS)\\d+"`

Comment: This is very useful. Thanks @Onyambu!

Answer (score 3):

The `pivot_longer()` function in tidyr can do the trick.  Use "name_pattern" to separate the front part(rep or SS) from the test/trial number.

```
library(tidyr)
pivot_longer(A, cols= -c("Season", "crop", "treatment", "plot", "row"), 
             names_pattern="(\\D+)(\\d)", names_to = c(".value", "test"))
#or
#pivot_longer(A, cols= matches("\\d$"), names_pattern="(\\D+)(\\d)", 
         names_to = c(".value", "test"))

# A tibble: 15 × 8
Season crop    treatment     plot   row test    rep SS   
<dbl> <chr>   <chr>        <dbl> <int> <chr> <dbl> <chr>
1   2023 Soybean Inside panel     6     1 1      24.3 tr1  
2   2023 Soybean Inside panel     6     1 2      10.3 tr3  
3   2023 Soybean Inside panel     6     1 3      30.7 tr2  
4   2023 Soybean Inside panel     6     2 1      30.3 tr1  
5   2023 Soybean Inside panel     6     2 2       0   tr2  
6   2023 Soybean Inside panel     6     2 3      28.4 tr3  
...
```

You will need to rename the columns to your final desired results.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I solved my problem!!

Answer (score 2):

Basically what you want is

```
> reshape(A, var=list(6:8, 9:11), sep='', dir='l')
```

To get desired column names we can refine

```
> reshape(A, var=list(6:8, 9:11), sep='', dir='l', v.names=c('yield', 'SS'), 
+         timevar='rep')
```

And finally to resemble sorting of the shown desired output

```
> reshape(A, var=list(6:8, 9:11), sep='', dir='l', v.names=c('yield', 'SS'),
+         timevar='rep') |> 
+   {\(.) .[with(., order(row, rep)), setdiff(names(.), 'id')]}()
    Season    crop    treatment plot row rep yield  SS
1.1   2023 Soybean Inside panel    6   1   1  24.3 tr1
1.2   2023 Soybean Inside panel    6   1   2  10.3 tr3
1.3   2023 Soybean Inside panel    6   1   3  30.7 tr2
2.1   2023 Soybean Inside panel    6   2   1  30.3 tr1
2.2   2023 Soybean Inside panel    6   2   2   0.0 tr2
2.3   2023 Soybean Inside panel    6   2   3  28.4 tr3
3.1   2023 Soybean Inside panel    6   3   1  21.8 tr1
3.2   2023 Soybean Inside panel    6   3   2  29.3 tr2
3.3   2023 Soybean Inside panel    6   3   3  15.5 tr3
4.1   2023 Soybean Inside panel    6   4   1  22.9 tr3
4.2   2023 Soybean Inside panel    6   4   2   0.0 tr2
4.3   2023 Soybean Inside panel    6   4   3  22.3 tr1
5.1   2023 Soybean Inside panel    6   5   1  20.6 tr1
5.2   2023 Soybean Inside panel    6   5   2  30.8 tr3
5.3   2023 Soybean Inside panel    6   5   3  17.4 tr2
```

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(A)
structure(list(Season = c(2023, 2023, 2023, 2023, 2023), crop = c("Soybean", 
"Soybean", "Soybean", "Soybean", "Soybean"), treatment = c("Inside panel", 
"Inside panel", "Inside panel", "Inside panel", "Inside panel"
), plot = c(6, 6, 6, 6, 6), row = 1:5, rep1 = c(24.3, 30.3, 21.8, 
22.9, 20.6), rep2 = c(10.3, 0, 29.3, 0, 30.8), rep3 = c(30.7, 
28.4, 15.5, 22.3, 17.4), SS1 = c("tr1", "tr1", "tr1", "tr3", 
"tr1"), SS2 = c("tr3", "tr2", "tr2", "tr2", "tr3"), SS3 = c("tr2", 
"tr3", "tr3", "tr1", "tr2")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```